# SQL query, necessery indexes, optimization

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, query-optimization

```
select * 
from ws 
where ws.id >= X and ws.id <= Y and w.ses = Z
```

Y - X < than 1 day, table contains data from the last 3 months. 
Performance of this query - select * from ws where ws.id = U is fine.

I don't have any information about the number of records in this table.

Table have an index on 'id', but DON'T HAVE the index on 'ses'.

What do you think about this? Is index on 'ses' necessary?

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 1):

For this query:

```
select * 
from ws 
where ws.id >= X and ws.id <= Y and w.ses = Z
```

The optimal index is on `ws(ses, id)`.  The order of the columns in the composite index is important.

Comment: thanks. interesting. why the order is important? and why id should be the second? What do you think about performance when index is only on id?

Comment: It is not that `id` should be second; it is that `ses` needs to be _first_ since it is tested with `=`.  Cookbook:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql